# How to keep only information inside a complex string in R?

Tags: r, regex, split, gsub

I want to keep a string of character inside a complex string. I think that I can use regex to do keep the thing that I need. Basically, I want to keep only the information between the `\"` and `\"` in `Function=\"SMAD5\"`. I also want to keep the empty strings: `Function=\"\"`

```
df=structure(1:6, .Label = c("ID=Gfo_R000001;Source=ENST00000513418;Function=\"SMAD5\";", 
"ID=Gfo_R000002;Source=ENSTGUT00000017468;Function=\"CENPA\";", 
"ID=Gfo_R000003;Source=ENSGALT00000028134;Function=\"C1QL4\";", 
"ID=Gfo_R000004;Source=ENSTGUT00000015300;Function=\"\";", "ID=Gfo_R000005;Source=ENSTGUT00000019268;Function=\"\";", 
"ID=Gfo_R000006;Source=ENSTGUT00000019035;Function=\"\";"), class = "factor")
```

This should look like this:

```
"SMAD5"
"CENPA"
"C1QL4"
NA
NA
NA
```

So far that What I was able to do:

```
gsub('.*Function=\"',"",df)

[1] "SMAD5\";" "CENPA\";" "C1QL4\";" "\";"      "\";"      "\";"
```

But I'm stuck with a bunch of `\";"`. How can I remove them with one line?

I tried this:

```
gsub('.*Function=\"' & '.\"*',"",test)
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
Error in ".*Function=\"" & ".\"*" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Comment: Try `gsub('.*Function=\"([^\"]*).*',"\\1",df)`

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub(".*Function=\"([^\"]*).*","\\1",df)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z6eOHv/1)

**Details**:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last...
- `Function=\"` - a `Function="` substring
- `([^\"]*)` - capturing group 1 matching 0+ chars other than a `"`
- `.*` - and the rest of the string.

The `\1`  is the backreference restoring the contents of the Group 1 in the result.

Answer (score 1):

With stringr we can capture groups too:

```
library(stringr)
matches <- str_match(df, ".*\"(.*)\".*")[,2]
ifelse(matches=='', NA, matches)
# [1] "SMAD5" "CENPA" "C1QL4" NA      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression can be constructed more readably using `rebus`.

```
rx <- 'Function="' %R% 
  capture(zero_or_more(negated_char_class('"')))
```

Then matching is as mentioned by Wiktor and sandipan.

```
rx <- 'Function="' %R% capture(zero_or_more(negated_char_class('"')))
str_match(df, rx)
stri_match_first_regex(df, rx)

gsub(any_char(0, Inf) %R% rx %R% any_char(0, Inf), REF1, df)
```

Comment: I never saw `%R%` operator before. Can you explain what it does? `??%R%` redirected me to `riemann.tensor {tensorA}`

Comment: @M.Beausoleil `%R%` is like `paste0()`, but as an operator, and for regular expressions. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rebus.base/topics/Concatenation